# Force Uploads Use Yearmonth to off (0) for all existing sites in Multisites

Tags: multisite, uploads

In WordPress Multisite, by default the site option **Uploads Use Yearmonth Folders** is on (set to 1). Is it possible to force this value for all existing sites in the Network?

Perhaps a hook?
I know that for new sites created one can use:

```
function simplify_upload_folder($blog_id){
    switch_to_blog($blog_id);
    update_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', false);
    restore_current_blog();
}
add_action('wpmu_new_blog', 'simplify_upload_folder');
```

But what about already existing sites can one force this value via an action or filter?

As an alternative to using a filter, I have written up the following to toggle the value in the DB but for some reason the field remains empty. Not sure where I am going wrong here:

```
if ( get_option( 'uploads_use_yearmonth_folders' ) == true || get_option( 'uploads_use_yearmonth_folders' ) == '' ) {
      switch_to_blog($blog_id);
      update_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', false);
      restore_current_blog();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'option_uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', '__return_false', 100 );
```

That's all you need, seriously!

Comment: You mean just that line? I tried it and the value is still set to 1? This should work on a single install although I have not tried it. What about multisite?

Comment: When you say the value is still set to 1, do you mean in the database? Because that's fine, the filter will always override it, and so is effective site-wide immediately.

Comment: Correct @TheDeadMedic you are totally right. You rock! How does that affect loading performance. I mean filtering versus DB query? I guess this also removes the possibility of some sites keeping the YYMM structure?

Comment: What I mean is that if you wanted to not force it for future sites created one would have to write the value to DB.

Comment: Zero impact. The filter will always override the user-saved setting. You'd need to write some additional checking logic to factor in future sites.

Comment: would you know how to update the value in the database? I have been pulling my hair out with it for the last 2 hours `code` function simplifyit_upload_folder($blog_id){
      switch_to_blog($blog_id);
      update_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', false);      
      restore_current_blog();
      }
      add_action( 'update_wpmu_options', 'simplifyit_upload_folder' ); `code`

Comment: May I ask why the need to do so?